# How can i see all available data series from quantmod package?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, quantmod

How to show which list of all quotes / data series  available for example with getSymbols from Yahoo?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know of a way.  The TTR package has a function (`stockSymbols`) to download all the current symbols from the NYSE, AMEX, and NASDAQ.  It tries to put them in an acceptable format for Yahoo, but there's no guarantee that the 6,000+ symbols it retrieves have data on Yahoo.  I'm not sure what to do for other exchanges...

```
> library(TTR)
> x <- stockSymbols()
Fetching AMEX symbols...
Fetching NASDAQ symbols...
Fetching NYSE symbols...
> str(x)
'data.frame':   6473 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Symbol   : chr  "ADK" "ADK-WT" "AFP" "AIM" ...
 $ Name     : chr  "Adcare Health Systems Inc" "Adcare Health Systems Inc" "United Capital Corporation" "Aerosonic Corporation" ...
 $ LastSale : num  4.12 2.1 30 2.73 2.7 ...
 $ MarketCap: num  3.28e+07 0.00 2.68e+08 1.02e+07 9.29e+07 ...
 $ IPOyear  : num  NA NA 1973 NA NA ...
 $ Sector   : chr  "Health Care" "n/a" "Capital Goods" "Capital Goods" ...
 $ Industry : chr  "Hospital/Nursing Management" "n/a" "Metal Fabrications" "Industrial Machinery/Components" ...
 $ Exchange : chr  "AMEX" "AMEX" "AMEX" "AMEX" ...
```

Comment: Note that `stockSymbols` in the version of TTR on CRAN is broken due to a change on nasdaq.com, but it is fixed in the R-forge version of TTR.

Comment: Is there a way I can get names of all the symbols listed in National Stock Exchange India. The stockSymbols fetches only US symbols