# How can I get all available data series names from quantmod and Quandl?

Tags: r, quantmod, quandl

I am interested in a large amount of free data from FRED, OECD, BIS, World-bank, etc. All data are macro-economic in nature. I am not really interested in stock price data.

I would essentially like to construct a CSV table with all symbols available for me in quantmod and Quandl. I am almost certain this table would be useful for others as well.

```
            Symbol,   Title,  Units,  Frequency
              X         X       X       X
              Y         Y       Y       Y
```

I found a similar question which has no answer.
[How can i see all available data series from quantmod package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219308/how-can-i-see-all-available-data-series-from-quantmod-package)

Is there a way to do this instead of searching FRED, OECD and manually on quandl on country by country and variable by variable level?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/cran/quantmod/tree/master/R

Comment: @joshuaulrich maintains `quantmod`

Answer (score 0):

Doe, on `Quandl` you can query the API for a dataset search, as described in this link:

```
https://www.quandl.com/docs/api#dataset-search
```

If you're using the `Quandl` package, you could use the `Quandl.search` function to build your query as specified in the above link. Here's the query from the link above using `Quandl.search`:

```
Quandl.search(query = "crude oil", page = 1, source = "DOE", silent = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, Quandl.search is a bit crude and does not really allow for a systematic way of capturing these time series.